# How come EDI can blow things up, but I can't?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So both EDI and I have incinerate, and I'm currently running through the Rachni Quest line. When I tell EDI to incinerate a Gestation pod it burns in a glorious explosion. However, when I do it, sometimes, but not all the time, it just fizzles and doesn't do any damage. Why is it that EDI can always destroy gestation pods with her explosions, and mine just fizzle? And why is it that mine just fizzle some of the time and not all the top? Please, help me perform.

Comment: Have you selected the same level 4, 5, or 6 options for both EDI and your Shep?

Comment: @CaulynDarr I am 1 level above EDI (at 5) and we both have the same level 4 upgrade.

Comment: NPCs have absurdly perfect aim if you manually order them to cast a skill, player casted skills seem more spotty. Especially Charge, which sometimes just DOESN'T WORK ARG STUPID REYSHG RAEDFAS ASDF

Comment: I can think of few theories.  Powers for squad members work differently(there's precedent for this from the previous games in how weapon damage worked).  EDI has better aim than you.  Or in commanding EDI to attack with an incinerate, she also fires her weapon at the same target.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AI's powers attack with perfect precision. Meanwhile, your powers will curve and fly through the air. This causes them to sometimes work incorrectly on small sized enemies, because the projectile hits the ground in front of the enemy.

It seems to work better if you try to purposely put exaggerated curve up and over to the enemy, so that your power hits them on top.

My advice though is to just shoot the pods with they flamethower, there's like a million ammo throughout the level.

Comment: All this talk of flamethrowers and pods makes me think:
They mostly come out at night. Mostly.

Comment: I was using power because on the gestation pods it also kills the swarmers on the inside, so I don't have to waste more ammo. Though, having finished that part now, I agree, there was no reason to try and conserve ammo.